# Redirecting shell application output to a file with HTA application

Tags: file, shell, redirect, hta

Can someone tell me why redirecting to a file does not work in my HTA program? It contains the following:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "md5sums.exe", "tarball.tar > .\md5sum.log", , , NORMAL_WINDOW
```

When I run my HTA program with the two above lines *without the redirect* it works fine. But the second I add the "> .\md5sum.log", md5sums.exe spits out the following error:

> ```
>  Unable to read file/directory .\md5sum.log
> ```

, meaning it's ignoring the redirect symbol and trying to take the checksum of the non-existent md5sum.log file.

md5sums.exe is simply an external checksum program. When I run the following from a command line, it works fine:

> ```
>  md5sums.exe tarball.tar > .\md5sum.log
> ```

, piping the checksum for tarball.tar to the md5sum.log file as expected.

I've searched high and low throughout the Interwebs, without finding a solution. I'd greatly appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out! In case anyone runs into this:

```
shellCmd = "cmd /c md5sums.exe ""tarball.tar"" > ""md5sum.log"""
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run shellCmd
```